# Creating a loadmask for a panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a `Ext.panel.panel`. How can I create a `LoadMask` for this panel so that anytime my store, `MyAwesomeStore`, makes a rest call, the panel gets masked while loading?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for loading a store when attached to a grid is that you should get the load mask without doing anything special.  The config looks like this to disable that behavior.

```
viewConfig: {
    loadMask: false
}
```

Comment: I dont want to disable it, it's not enabled and i need to enable it.

Comment: the default behavior should be loadMask: true.  I showed the example of turning it to non-default behavior.  I would suggest trying this viewconfig with loadMask set to true (though that should not be necessary).  Do you have enough delay in your load data call so that a loadmask will come up if it is working? (at least a second to test)